# RDLC report Previous function not working

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I'm trying to get previous row value in RDLC report using `=Previous(Fields!IN.Value)` expression and it gives me run time error "An error occurred during local report processing" I'm using report viewer version 12.0.0.0 in my C# desktop application.

Comment: Is this column `IN` in your xsd ? Remove `Previous` function to check is it work ?

Comment: Yes It works when "Previous" function removed and yes column 'IN' is in my xsd. Any solution for this?

Comment: It is not clearly ! What you can try is to create new test project then create simple xsd and rdlc with previous function.